# How to subscribe to an observable multiple times?

Tags: angular, service, observable

In the ngOnInit() of my Angular app, I'm subscribing to an Observable like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadArtistTable();
    }

loadArtistTable(): void {
    this._artistService.getArtists().subscribe(
        (artistList) => this.artists = artistList,
        (err) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

This is working fine as the artist details are being retrieved & displayed in a table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let artist of artists">
    <td>{{artist.fullName}}</td>
    <td>{{artist.email}}</td>
    <td>{{artist.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{artist.contactPreference}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editButtonClick(artist.id)">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

I then have a form which I use to update Artist details. After I update the details & click Save, a PUT request is sent & the Artist is updated successfully.

When I refresh the browser, the new Artist details are being displayed.

Now, I am trying to refresh the Artist table when the Save button is clicked. 
Here is the code executed when I click Save:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel();
    this._artistService.updateArtist(this.artist).subscribe(
        () => console.log('artist updated successfully'),
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
    this.loadArtistTable();
}
```

As I mentioned above, the artist is being updated, but the table is not being populated with the latest data when the button is clicked.

Can someone please tell me why *this.loadArtistTable();* isn't being executed in my *onSubmit()* function, & a possible solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try moving `this.loadArtistTable();` inside of the `subscribe` callback.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks a lot for that, it worked a treat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by placing *this.loadArtistTable()* inside the *subscribe* callback like so:

```
onSubmit(): void {
    this.mapFormValuesToEmployeeModel();
    this._artistService.updateArtist(this.artist).subscribe(
      () => (console.log('artist updated successfully'), this.loadArtistTable()),
      (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

—————————————
Warning:
 For every update record you are calling list of 1000 records which been a load when record increases so when you update record you have to update particular record from list using splice